# Selecionar determinado valor de Input

Tags: php, html, input

Galera, estou finalizando um projeto, pelo qual o usuário bipa (leitor código de barras) num input o código de barras de uma nota fiscal e preciso retornar somente o número da nota fiscal (9 posições) em outro input.

A posição da chave são de 44 caracteres. Preciso selecionar do caracter 25 até 34 para obter o número da nota.
Podem me ajudar?
abraço

Comment: Amigo edite a sua pergunta como o que vc ja tem de código, ou os inputs com os números etc.

Comment: Pode dar um exemplo um pouco mais específico?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php):

```
$codigo = "01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123";
$nota = substr($codigo, 24, 9);
```

O primeiro parâmetro você passa a variável, no segundo a posição inicial (posição 0 = 1° caracter, posição 24 = 25° caracter) e no terceiro, quantos caracteres a partir do inicial